# Providing base class constructor parameters when creating a derived class instance

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, new-operator, parent-child

Is there a way to provide constructor parameters to a base class when new-ing a derived class instance? (That is, when the base class constructor has default values for these parameters)

E.g.

```
class Base
{
public:
 Base::Base( string name = "" )
 : m_name( name ) {};

private
 string m_name;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
 Derived::Derived() {};
};
```

Then I need to do something like this:

```
void main()
{
 Base* instance = new Derived( "Jeff" );
};
```

This obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to new a derived instance and provide a constructor parameter to it's base without having to provide that parameter in the derived class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to new a derived instance and provide a constructor parameter to it's base without having to provide that parameter in the derived class constructor.

No.

Your derived-class constructor needs to take the arguments, and explicitly pass them down to the base-class constructor.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
 Derived::Derived(string name) : Base(name) {};
};
```

This is the case regardless of whether you're using `new` or not.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to avoid having to provide the parameter in the derived constructor. Is this the only way?

Comment: @MarcusTomlinson: Pretty much.  Obviously, there are variants of what I've suggested, but they all involve the `Derived` constructor explicitly invoking the `Base` constructor in its initialisation list.  But this makes sense; the fact that `Derived` is derived from `Base` is an implementation detail at construction time; that fact is essentially encapsulated.

Comment: If you don't want to change constructors, you could add properties that can be set post-construction (e.g. a `setName(string)` method in `Base`).  Then if someone default-constructs a `Derived` instance they can subsequently call `instance.setName("Jeff")`.

Comment: Really my main concern is that the variable be set up front and only once -using a setter won't satisfy the former but could satisfy the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it if you want distinct names into base class. however distinct name is not a criteria, you can do it using passing constant literals as:

```
class Base
{
public:
 Base::Base( string name = "" )
 : m_name( name ) {};

private
 string m_name;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
 Derived::Derived() : Base ("Jeff")    {};
 Derived::Derived(string &name) : Base (name) {};
};
```

OR pass default value to Derived class constructor.

```
class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
     Derived::Derived(string name = "Jeff") : Base (name) {};
    };
```